# Which return type is better? SortedSet or a list that is sorted

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, set

In my code I have a function that processes some data and then return a list that should be sorted. I have 2 options for the return:
- SortedSet
- List (but it will be sorted)

The only operation done on this return type so far is iterating.

Argument for SortedSet:
- It forces the items returned to be sorted
- It implies the items returned are sorted

Argument for a List:
- The caller does not need a Set (and its complex functionality), all he needs is a list of items that are promised to be sorted.
- Keeping the interface simple (no SortedList)

What do you think?

Comment: Why would sorted set be simpler than sorted list?

Comment: "The only operation done on this return type so far is iterating."  That should give you your answer right there: *return the minimum type necessary for the caller to iterate* -- `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: If you to make the promise that the returned collection is sorted then put that promise in the method name instead of the return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not return IEnumerable? 
That way your other functions don't have to worry about using specifically SortedSet or List.
Also is simpler to handle an IEnumerable than an specific object, generally using interfaces is a good practice, because adds flexibility to to your classes and your projects in general, making them more scalable.